# Limit GridView Columns

Tags: asp.net, html, css, gridview

I have a gridview which is displaying products information (code below) 
now I would like to limit description field so that only the first few is shown if there is a long description and also resize the image to fit in the image column (and making the image, description column a bit bigger than the others

Thanks

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvProducts" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ProductId" OnRowDeleting="gvProducts_RowDeleting" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvProducts_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Productname" HeaderText="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductDescription" HeaderText="Description"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductSupplier" HeaderText="Supplier" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductCategory" HeaderText="Category" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductSubCategory" HeaderText="SubCategory" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductVAT" HeaderText="VAT" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductStock" HeaderText="Stock" />
        <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="ProductImage" HeaderText="Image"/>
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="ProductActive" HeaderText="Active" />
        <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" ShowDeleteButton="True" />
    </Columns>
    <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="selectedrow" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: You could shorten the product description in your SQL, before it even gets to your GridView.

Answer (score 1):

Using **css** we can limit the description text to be displayed. Like this....

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvProducts" runat="server" CssClass="GridCSS" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ProductId" OnRowDeleting="gvProducts_RowDeleting" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvProducts_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <Columns>
-----------------------
-----------
---------
<asp:BoundField DataField="ProductDescription" HeaderText="Description" ItemStyle-CssClass="limittext" />
------------------
---------
-------------

</Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

CSS style:

```
.GridCSS {
        table-layout:fixed; 
        width:100%; 
    }
    .GridCSS .limittext{
        overflow: hidden; 
        text-overflow: ellipsis; 
        white-space: nowrap;        
    }
```

Comment: Regarding the image field, what css code can I use to re-size/make the image fit in the griedview?

Answer (score 0):

You can use mask for fw 4.5 or some external pluging lika Jquery Mask. 
or You can make them Template Item and put some code like <%# Eval("ProductDescription").SubString(0,50) %>

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with MVC, you can alter your GridView's data in your controller before binding it to GW. If you're not using MVC, the only thing I can offer is: in your RowDataBound event, check if description exceeds your defined max. chars and then truncate it.

Not a proper answer I know, but it may give you a few ideas. Can't provide code right now as I'm at work, but I'll check later if there is no answer to your post.

For further reading:

http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/43687-How-show-formatted-html-content-grid-view.aspx
http://forums.asp.net/t/1391922.aspx/1

Comment: Not using mvc, normal asp.net. Tried to do it with css but layout was still not as I wish

Comment: Do you want to truncate displayed data on the GW before it gets to it or add a Javascript effect on the row to truncate it and display full text on mouse over?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">
<ItemTemplate>

<%# Eval("ProductDescription").ToString().Length > 50 ? Eval("ProductDescription").ToString().Substring(0,50)+"..." : Eval("ProductDescription").ToString() %>

</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

If text is more than 50 characters, display first 50, otherwise, display the whole text.

Another option is return a shortDescription from the database or from the Product object

```
 public string ShortDescription
 {
    get 
    { 
        return ProductDescription.Length > 50 ? ProductDescription.Substring(0,50) : ProductDescription;
    }
 }
```

Comment: 2nd method is not good for me as I would still want the whole description to be displayed in a textbox when a product is selected.

Comment: Also item template does not containt DataField so that I can link column with databse

Comment: Values are not picked from the Grid but the underline DataItem that populates each row. So everything is intact, only what is displayed

Answer (score 0):

```
<table style="table-layout: fixed">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <telerik:RadGrid ID="radGVEmployee" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" GridLines="None"
                                AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellSpacing="0" OnNeedDataSource="radGVEmployee_NeedDataSource"
                                Visible="True" OnSortCommand="radGVEmployee_SortCommand" AllowPaging="true" OnPageIndexChanged="radGVEmployee_PageIndexChanged"
                                Width="900px" OnItemDataBound="radGVEmployee_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="radGVEmployee_ItemCommand"
                                PageSize="5">
                                <FilterMenu EnableTheming="True">
                                    <CollapseAnimation Duration="200" Type="OutQuint" />
                                </FilterMenu>
                                <GroupingSettings CaseSensitive="False" />
                                <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="UsrId" AllowFilteringByColumn="true" TableLayout="Fixed"
                                    Visible="true" AllowMultiColumnSorting="false">
                                    <NoRecordsTemplate>
                                        <div style="width: 700px;" align="center">
                                            There is No Data to display</div>
                                    </NoRecordsTemplate>
                                    <CommandItemSettings ExportToPdfText="Export to PDF" />
                                    <RowIndicatorColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter RowIndicator column" Visible="True">
                                    </RowIndicatorColumn>
                                    <ExpandCollapseColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter ExpandColumn column" Visible="True">
                                    </ExpandCollapseColumn>
                                    <Columns>
                                        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn SortExpression="UserName" DataField="UserName" HeaderText="UserName"
                                            HeaderStyle-Width="60px" FilterControlWidth="75%" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblItmUserName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UserName") %>'></asp:Label>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Wrap="false"></HeaderStyle>
                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                                        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn SortExpression="FullName" DataField="FullName" HeaderText="FullName"
                                            HeaderStyle-Width="60px" FilterControlWidth="75%" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblItmFullName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FullName") %>'></asp:Label>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Wrap="false"></HeaderStyle>
                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                                        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn SortExpression="MobileNo" DataField="MobileNo" HeaderText="MobileNo"
                                            HeaderStyle-Width="40px" FilterControlWidth="75%" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblItmMobileNo" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MobileNo") %>'></asp:Label>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Wrap="false"></HeaderStyle>
                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                                        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn SortExpression="CompanyName" DataField="CompanyName"
                                            HeaderText="CompanyName" HeaderStyle-Width="50px" FilterControlWidth="75%" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblItmCompanyName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CompanyName") %>'></asp:Label>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Wrap="false"></HeaderStyle>
                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                                        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn SortExpression="BranchName" DataField="BranchName" HeaderText="BranchName"
                                            HeaderStyle-Width="50px" FilterControlWidth="75%" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblItmBranchName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("BranchName") %>'></asp:Label>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Wrap="false"></HeaderStyle>
                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                                        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn SortExpression="Designation" DataField="Designation"
                                            HeaderText="Designation" HeaderStyle-Width="50px" FilterControlWidth="75%" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblItmDesignation" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Designation") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblItmLockStatus" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LockStatus") %>'
                                                    Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblItmUserStatus" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UserStatus") %>'
                                                    Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Wrap="false"></HeaderStyle>
                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                                        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn SortExpression="UserImage" DataField="UserImage" HeaderText="UserImage"
                                            HeaderStyle-Width="50px" FilterControlWidth="75%" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                                            AllowFiltering="false">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Image ID="lblUserImage" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("ImageName")!=DBNull.Value? 
                                                  System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureImagePath"]+Eval("ImageName"):System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserImagePath"]+"profile-empty-head.gif"%>'
                                                    Height="100px" Width="90px" />
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Wrap="false"></HeaderStyle>
                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                                        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn AllowFiltering="false" DataField="Actions" HeaderText="Actions"
                                            HeaderStyle-Width="50px" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                            <%--OnClientClick='radconfirm("Are you sure you want to Change this LockStatus?", ClientGridCallback,300,150); return false;' --%>
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="imgLockStatus" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/DefaultClient/images/unlock.png"
                                                    CommandName="ChangeLockStatus" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("UsrId") %>' ToolTip="UserLockStatus"
                                                    AlternateText="LockStatus" OnClientClick="return blockConfirm('Are you sure you want to Change Lock Status?', event, 340, 150,'','Change Lock Status')" />
                                                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="imgUserStatus" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/DefaultClient/images/select.png"
                                                    CommandName="ChangeUserStatus" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("UsrId") %>' ToolTip="UserActivationStatus"
                                                    AlternateText="UserActivationStatus" OnClientClick="return blockConfirm('Are you sure you want to Change Activation Status?', event, 340, 150,'','Change Activation Status')" />
                                                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="imgResetPassword" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/DefaultClient/images/logoff.png"
                                                    CommandName="ResetPassword" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("UsrId") %>' ToolTip="ResetPassword"
                                                    Width="22px" Height="22px" AlternateText="ResetPassword" OnClientClick="return blockConfirm('Are you sure you want to Reset Password?', event, 340, 150,'','Reset Password')"  />
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Wrap="false"></HeaderStyle>
                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                                        <%--   <telerik:GridButtonColumn ConfirmText="Are you sure you want to Change LockStatus ?<br /><br /><br />"
                                            ConfirmDialogType="RadWindow" HeaderStyle-Width="15px" ConfirmDialogHeight="150px"
                                            HeaderText="LockStatus" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" CommandName="ChangeLockStatus"
                                            ButtonType="ImageButton" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/DefaultClient/images/unlock.png"
                                            ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ConfirmTitle="Delete Currency" UniqueName="ChangeLockStatus">
                                        </telerik:GridButtonColumn>
                                        <telerik:GridButtonColumn ConfirmText="Are you sure you want to Change ActivationStatus ?<br /><br /><br />"
                                            ConfirmDialogType="RadWindow" HeaderStyle-Width="15px" ConfirmDialogHeight="150px"
                                            HeaderText="ActivationStatus" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" CommandName="ChangeUserStatus"
                                            ButtonType="ImageButton" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/DefaultClient/images/unlock.png"
                                            ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ConfirmTitle="Delete Currency" UniqueName="ChangeUserStatus">
                                        </telerik:GridButtonColumn>--%>
                                    </Columns>
                                    <EditFormSettings>
                                        <EditColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter EditCommandColumn column">
                                        </EditColumn>
                                    </EditFormSettings>
                                </MasterTableView>
                                <GroupingSettings CaseSensitive="False" />
                                <ClientSettings>
                                    <ClientEvents OnGridCreated="GridCreated" />
                                </ClientSettings>
                                <PagerStyle Mode="NextPrevAndNumeric"></PagerStyle>
                            </telerik:RadGrid>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

Try this ..........